# Retrieve path of tmpfile()

Tags: php

Quickie...

Is there a way to retrieve the path of a file created by `tmpfile()`?

Or do I need to do it myself with `tempnam()`?

Answer (score 127, accepted):

It seems [stream_get_meta_data()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-get-meta-data.php) also works :

```
$tmpHandle = tmpfile();
$metaDatas = stream_get_meta_data($tmpHandle);
$tmpFilename = $metaDatas['uri'];
fclose($tmpHandle);
```

Comment: +1 For actually answering the question. As of PHP 5.3 you can simply use `stream_get_meta_data($tmpHandle)['uri']`.

Comment: $foo()['bar'] not work on my PHP 5.3.13, but otherwise this answer is correct answer on question asked above.

Comment: Great! sys_get_temp_dir() not available on old php 5.1 server :(

Comment: Of course you cannot access this file any more after `fclose()` call, [it deletes the temporary file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.tmpfile.php).

Comment: searched for this for about an hour..!

Comment: I am getting this error using this code. stream_get_meta_data() expects parameter 1 to be resource, bool given in

Comment: @jayeshkavathiya then `tmpfile()` returned false.

Answer (score -1):

Like this

```
$path = array_search('uri', @array_flip(stream_get_meta_data($GLOBALS[mt_rand()]=tmpfile()))); 
file_put_contents($path, 'hello');
```