# PHP. Transferring downloaded csv to mysql database - how can I store downloaded csv file in php memory

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I would like to store data downloaded from a website into my mysql database.

I use my function "CallAPI("GET", $url, $data = false)" to access the database using a url such as "http://www.xflow1.com/xGlobalHist.csv/"...

So my call $results = CallAPI($method, $url, $data = false); returns a comma delimted array that is saved in the variable "$results". I can echo $results in a web page and it show me the data, all comma delimited. All good `til here.

To upload the csv to my mysql database I want to use the "LOAD DATA INFILE" function as so:

```
$upload = <<<eof
LOAD DATA INFILE $results
INTO TABLE X_Adjusted_All
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(Cusip, Date, Price)
 eof;
```

The snag arises as "LOAD DATA INFILE $results" does not work as LOAD DATA INFILE only wants a filename, so I would like to store $results as a csv file in the memory to avoid creating and deleting files all the time. I thought this may work:

```
$fp = fopen('php://memory', 'w');
fputcsv($fp, $results);
```

Alas no. Does anyone have any idea how to take the downloaded csv file and save it to the phps memory as a csv file for use in the LOAD DATA INFILE function?

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't use a regular file?

Comment: You can't allocate a part of memory with PHP and then have MySQL read it using LOAD DATA INFILE. What you could do, if you are into performance to that level - create a ram drive and save the csv file there. Then have MySQL read it.

Comment: @Andy on reflection I think my issue is that I can download the data fine when I call the function in the line: $results = CallAPI("GET", $url, $data = false), but I can't do anything with the subsequent data in the variable $results. I simply do not know how to save $results as a csv file.

Comment: That is shown in the example of tempnam() see updated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL cannot read directly from PHP's memory. You need to create an external file using [`tempnam()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.tempnam.php). That file can then be read by MySQL. You could also create a temporary file and find out the filename as mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11212569/retrieve-path-of-tmpfile).

The example of `tempnam()` shows how to write to that file:

```
<?php
$tmpfname = tempnam("/tmp", "FOO");

$handle = fopen($tmpfname, "w");
fwrite($handle, $results);
fclose($handle);

// do something

unlink($tmpfname);
```

This will store the contents of `$results` to a file called `$tmpfname` which you can store in mysql using `LOAD DATA INFILE $tmpfname`.

As mentioned in the comments, you could create a ram drive to store that file, if performance is an issue.