# How to get the path of a file create with tmpfile()

Tags: php, file

I just create a temp file with [`tmpfile`](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.tmpfile.php) in order to put into it a file I get from a remote FTP server.

I need to pass to an API the URL to this file, but `tmpfile` return a resource... How can I retrieve its path?

Comment: It will be created in the folder returned by a call to `sys_get_temp_dir()`; but perhaps you should be using [tempnam()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.tempnam.php) if you need to know the actual filename

Comment: possible duplicate of [Retrieve path of tmpfile()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11212569/retrieve-path-of-tmpfile)

Answer (score 1):

Actually,
`stream_get_meta_data($file)['uri']`
should contain the path.